# Dose incorrect password timeout in windows apply for both phyical and remote desktop logins?

Tags: windows-10

Dose the incorrect password timeout setting in windows 10 apply for both physical (a user sitting at the computer) and remote desktop (Microsoft remote desktop) logins ?

Comment: Yes of course it does

Comment: Those only thing to consider if you are bench marking the time or something is at the console is likely to respond to the initial request milliseconds quicker perhaps since it does not need to go over the network as it goes when you try to authenticate via Remote Desktop.

Comment: Does anyone connect via dial up any more.... lol